# Problem with photobox webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I want to use a picturebox webpart in a SharePoint 2013 portal from http://sharepointpicturebox.codeplex.com/documentation,  but it does not work based on the documentation.

I read  from the documentation of it:

> Step 2 Load the picture library with the files images that you want to
>   show, set the OpenTo column property with a valid and complete http
>   web address.

What does it mean? I could not see my picture in webpart it just show the name of the picture library.

Answer (score 0):

- In your library, create a column field called `OpenTo` as `Hyperlink` or `Text`.
- Set its value with a valid hyperlink for the image URL.
- Then at web part properties set the document library name.

[image]

Comment: hi   what do you mean by   Set its value with a valid hyperlink for the image URL?

Comment: when you add new item set this field value with a valid image url

Comment: I have noted that you don't accept any answer or upvote it so please don't forget to take a tour at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour and upvote and set as asnwer if it's helped you , thanks